# "Same Bundle ID" error when installing exactly the same APP into the same iOS device after the App transfer to different developer

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile, bundle-identifier

So I got an App that I re-create using Flutter.
It is an iOS App. It is live in the App Store. But I just transferred it from one developer account to another (both owned by me).

Now I'm trying to test the upgrade on my device and it gives me this error:

```
Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653008
--
This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653008
```

But it is supposedly exactly the same App, thus the bundle ID should be the same. I also tried to change that but it gives me another error.

More info:

- I use the same bundle ID.
- I create a new provisioning profile with the new developer account of course but with the same bundle ID.

Did I miss anything? Thanks for all the help